# ¿Como pasar un array guardado en la sessionStorage con javascript al controlador para poder recorrerlo?

Tags: javascript, mvc, razor

Necesito pasar un `array` creado en `javascript` que esta guardado en una `sessionStorage` al `controlador`(el array contiene id de libros).
Desde el controlador recorrería el `array` para obtener los datos, estos mismos los voy a usar en una función para Obtener una `lista` de libros. esta lista la enviaría a una `View`llamada `Comprar.cshtml`, donde voy a mostrar la lista en una `tabla`. Cuando vaya a la `view` para mostrar la lista quiero quedarme parado en esa view Comprar.cshtml.
Mi idea es que a través del `evento onclick` de un `boton`llame a una función "comprar" de `javascript`para que pueda pasar el `array` guardado en la `sessionStorage` al `controlador`. Tengo La función hecha, pero le falta poder pasar el `array` al `controlador` (no se como hacerlo!) esta es la función:

```js
function comprar() {

        var ides = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('arrayId'));

        //compruebo array vacio
        if (arrId.length === 0)
            alert("El carro esta vacío!, agregue un libro.")
        
        else
        {
             //aca la logica para pasar el array al controlador          
        }
    }
```

el controlador:

```html
 public ActionResult Comprar()
{
            
          
    return View();     
}
```

Comment: la respuesta a tu pregunta es... [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Gracias @ Paulo Urbano Rivera! como seria el código?, soy novato en $.ajax

Comment: En la documentación que te deje está todo explicado. Sólo debes usar $.ajax para conectar tu front a tu back (o el back de terceros), enviando la uri, el método, parámetros, etc etc etc. Tú puedes hacerlo :D

Comment: ok gracias!!!!!